# Problem with Netplan and Ubuntu 18.04 taking down our network after "netplan apply" command is run

Tags: ubuntu, ip, systemd

We are trying to add additional IPs to our OVH server and whenever we apply the command "netplan apply" after making our yaml changes, the server completely goes offline.  The network is down.  This happens for about 10-15 minutes before it comes back on its own.

When i run a command to check the status of systemd-networkd i get the following:

```
● systemd-networkd.service - Network Service
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Sun 2018-12-02 05:10:18 UTC; 26min ago
Docs: man:systemd-networkd.service(8)
Main PID: 40782 (systemd-network)
Status: "Processing requests..."
Tasks: 1 (limit: 8601)
CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-networkd.service
       └─40782 /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd

Dec 02 05:10:18 servername systemd-networkd[40782]: eno1: Gained IPv6LL
Dec 02 05:10:18 servername systemd-networkd[40782]: Enumeration completed
Dec 02 05:10:18 servername systemd[1]: Started Network Service.
Dec 02 05:10:18 servername systemd-networkd[40782]: eno2: Could not find udev device: No such device
Dec 02 05:10:18 servername systemd-networkd[40782]: eno2: Failed
Dec 02 05:10:18 servername systemd-networkd[40782]: Could not add new link, ignoring: No such device
Dec 02 05:10:18 servername systemd-networkd[40782]: lo: Link is not managed by us
Dec 02 05:10:18 servername systemd-networkd[40782]: eno1: DHCPv4 address [ip address]/24 via <my server ip address>    
Dec 02 05:10:18 ns536095 systemd-networkd[40782]: eno1: Configured
Dec 02 05:10:18 ns536095 systemd-networkd[40782]: eth0: Interface name change detected, eth0 has been renamed to eno2.
```

It seems that it's trying to search for eno2 but that doesn't exist which causes the timing out and dropping of our network completely.  All of our IPs are set on eno1.   There is nothing for eno2 although the server does have that network card.

How can i solve this issue?   Been trying to figure this out for the longest time.  The yaml file is confirmed to be proper in the following format.

```
network:
version: 2
ethernets:
    eno1:
        dhcp4: true
        addresses: [<Main IP>, <additional ip>]
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just an update, when i reboot the server the errors go away but as soon as i enter "netplan apply" it brings my server down for 10-15 minutes.

Comment: Anybody have a solution to this...every reboot we do takes over 10 minutes long and i have no idea what is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a similar problem, but the interface does not come back automatically after 10-15 minutes.
I've the problem with bridged interfaces ...

```
  bridges:
    br0:
      addresses:
        - 10.0.1.1/16
        - 172.16.0.1/21
      interfaces:
        - enp2s0f0
        - enp2s0f1
        - enp2s0f2
        - enp2s0f3
```

Answer (score 0):

We've seen a similar problem and found that designating connections as "critical" fixes the issue:

```
ethernets:
    eno1:
        dhcp4: false
        addresses: [<Main IP>, <additional ip>]
        critical: true
```

Unfortunately the documentation for the "critical" flag is currently rather sparse, so it's difficult to tell whether there are any downsides to designating a connection as "critical", particularly for non-DHCP ports.